# Remove all character after non ascii charater in all column

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a bash script which will remove all the Non Ascii character from the file. But i wanted to remove the string after the non Ascii character in all the columns. Below is the script,

```
> #!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_PATH=/trmout/TRMOUTPUT_PROD
BKP_PATH=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/Temp_Files/SUPPLY_CHAIN

File_Name=WB


########################################################################
##Deleting the precessed files ####
########################################################################

cd $BKP_PATH
rm *.*

#########################################################################
### removing the non ascii char from all Supply chain files #######
#########################################################################

for i in $SCRIPT_PATH/$File_Name*.txt
do

cp $i $BKP_PATH

##########################################################################
##Replacing the NON ASCII Char from Supply Chain files and saving it.####
##########################################################################
cat $i  >> $i.bkp

sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' $i.bkp

mv $i.bkp $i

done


#############################################################################################
##Creating a sample file which will be having the file name which has NON ASCII Char in it.##
#############################################################################################

cd $SCRIPT_PATH

grep -vlP '^[\0-\x7f]*$' WB*.txt >Supply_chain_Non_Ascii_List_File.txt
~
~
```

Comment: post a testable input file fragment

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to delete anything on the line after the first non-ascii character ? If not, please provides some examples.

If yes, your sed should be :

```
sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255].*$//' $i.bkp
```

This will replace the first non-ascii character AND the rest of the line with nothing.

Comment: sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255][^|]*|/|/' WB*  < $i.bkp This will replace the first non-ascii character till the first Column seperated by |.